# What are my options for cross browser testing in an environment where security is of high concern

Tags: testing, cross-browser

I am looking for options to set up cross browser testing at our organization. Our clients use only IE 9 and up so my test environment will only require IE 9/10/11/Edge and should allow the tester to ma

Due to the nature of our work security is of high concern so we cannot invest in any tool unless we are absolutely sure that the probability of a compromise is minimal. I am currently looking into Browserstack and Saucelabs. I had also looked into modern.ie but it's licensing does not allow it to be used for 'commercial' purposes.

Would love to hear what has worked for others in similar situations.

Comment: If security is paramount, you probably won't be able to use any external tool at all, as you'll have to make whatever you are testing available to the public. This is very unclear as to what exactly the sensitive nature of your situation is though - what kind of threat are you anticipating? What kind of attacks do you want to prevent?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just IE that you're testing on, why not use the built-in Emulation in IE Edge (Developer Tools F12)? You can emulate browsers back to IE7.

Of course that's never going to be 100% as good as the actual browser, but it could be enough depending on your needs.

Comment: We are currently running on Windows 7, so won't be able to install Edge.

Comment: So you say you work on a security critical system and don't have the resource to get a machine with the OS you need to properly test it? Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclosure: I work in the Product team at BrowserStack. I know you've asked others for what has worked for them but I thought I'll post a reply nonetheless.**

We work with a number of large enterprises (including many banks which probably have the most stringent security requirements). Our Security is pretty robust and I'll be happy to share documentation around this if you'd like. You can reach out to me at arpitrai at browserstack. More information here in case you haven't referred to it already https://www.browserstack.com/security.